# C struct encoded binary data file read in python

Tags: python

This code reads binary file. Read data is converted into signed values and gets plotted if the user wants it.

Binary file has below struct data encoded consecutively till the end.

```
    struct __attribute__((__packed__)) test_data
    {
        uint16_t division;
        int16_t fast_velocity; 
        int16_t test_velocity; 
        int16_t test_position; 
        int16_t another_test_velocity;
    };
```

I am reading this data from the file byte by byte and using 2's complement to convert this in signed values. Is there any better way than below in python?

**Data looks as below:**

`00000000: 0800 01dc 0500 02a4 0000 88ff f918 a9ff  ................
 00000010: fa53 88ff 3200 0161 2d00 029a 2e00 feff  .S..2..a-.......
 00000020: f933 f6ff fa14 efff ebff f9bf eaff fa0e  .3..............
 00000030: eaff 2500 0132 1700 0232 1f00 eeff f9ef  ..%..2...2......
 00000040: eeff fa73 e6ff f3ff f9a6 efff fa9c f5ff  ...s............
 00000050: ecff f92c ebff fa69 eaff ffff 0188 0100  ...,...i........
 00000060: fabd f6ff 0500 01d6 0300 0211 0100 1400  ................
 00000070: 0177 1400 0205 1400 0f00 017b 0e00 02e5  .w.........{....
 00000080: 0400 ffff f949 ffff fab3 fbff 0000 01f9  .....I..........
 00000090: 0100 fa3f f3ff ffff f94c fcff fa2e f7ff  ...?.....L......
 000000a0: 0200 01ad 0200 027a 0100 1b00 015c 1500  .......z.....\..
 000000b0: 026a 1400 1200 0183 0d00 02cf 0e00 1200  .j..............
 000000c0: 01f0 0a00 02c1 0d00 ffff f977 f9ff fa48  ...........w...H
 000000d0: faff 1000 01eb 0400 02cb 0000 1400 0178  ...............x`

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import struct
from optparse import OptionParser
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
import binascii
import time
import math


def twos_complement(hexstr, bits):
    value = int(hexstr,16)
    if value & (1 << (bits-1)):
        value -= 1 << bits
    return value


def reverse_digits(s):
    if len(s) != 4:
        print("wrong length passed %d!!"% (len(s)))
        return None
    return s[2:] + s[0:2]


params_information = OrderedDict([("division", (5, 5)), ("fast_velocity", (30, -30)), ("test_velocity", (60, -60)), ("test_position", (22, -22)), ("another_test_velocity", (28, -28))])


class TESTParams():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.all_params = {}
        self.param_size = 20

    def get_param(self, param):
        return self.all_params[param]

    def plot_param(self, param):
        # Create a figure of size 8x6 inches, 80 dots per inch
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
        # Create a new subplot from a grid of 1x1
        plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
        plt.xlabel(str(param))
        plt.ylabel("limits")
        x = np.linspace(params_information[param][0], params_information[param][1], num=len(self.all_params[param]))
        plt.plot(x, self.all_params[param])
        plt.show()

    def get_all_params(self):
        """
        gets division/fast/test/another_test velocity and position from file
        file format is binary and it has data in below format repeated till EOF
        struct __attribute__((__packed__)) test_data
        {
            uint16_t division;
            int16_t fast_velocity; 
            int16_t test_velocity; 
            int16_t test_position; 
            int16_t another_test_velocity;
        };
        Below code does converts raw characters read from file into signed 16 bit numbers
        before adding to the dictionary.
        """
        with open(self.file_name) as file:
            data = file.read()
            hex_data = binascii.hexlify(data)
            for i in range(0, len(hex_data), self.param_size):
                test_data = hex_data[i:i+self.param_size]
                j = 0
                division = 0
                for param in params_information:
                    if not param in self.all_params:
                        self.all_params[param] = []
                    if param == "division":
                        division = float(twos_complement(reverse_digits(test_data[j:j+4]), 16))
                        if division == 0:
                            print("division is 0!!")
                            return
                        self.all_params[param].append(float(division))
                    else:
                        self.all_params[param].append(float(twos_complement(reverse_digits(test_data[j:j+4]), 16)/division))
                    j += 4


def main():
    parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [options] filename -p -v",
                          version="%prog 1.0")
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest='filename',
                      help="file name to get test data from")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--print_all_params", default=False, dest='print_all_params',
                      help="print all params division/fast/test/another_test velocities and position", action='store_true')
    parser.add_option("-o", "--plot_param", default=False, dest='plot_param',
                      help="plot param, pass - division , fast_velocity, test_velocity , test_position another_test_velocity")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.filename:
        parser.error('Filename not given')

    p = TESTParams(options.filename)
    p.get_all_params()
    if options.verify and p.verify_all_params():
        pass

    if options.print_all_params:
        for i, j, k, l, m in zip(p.get_param("division"), p.get_param("fast_velocity"),
                                 p.get_param("test_velocity"), p.get_param("test_position"),
                                 p.get_param("another_test_velocity")):
            print("division [%f] fast_velocity[%f] test_velocity[%f] test_position[%f] another_test_velocity[%f]"% (i, j, k, l, m))

    if options.plot_param in params_information:
        p.plot_param(options.plot_param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please let me know why this downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html). For example:

```
with open('whatever.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# I am assuming little-endian data based on your existing code.
division, fast_velocity, test_velocity, test_position, another_test_velocity = struct.unpack_from("<H4h", data)
# that is: specify little-endian, then read an unsigned 16-bit value,
# followed by four signed 16-bit values.
```